# Настройка конфигурации моделей Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть таблицы: `Products`, `Tags` и связывающая их `ProductTags`

Модели:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Конфигурация:

```
public class TagConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Tag>
{
    public TagConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(tag => tag.Products)
            .WithMany(product => product.Tags)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("ProductTags");
                x.MapLeftKey("TagId");
                x.MapRightKey("ProductId");
            });
    }
}
```

Нужно добавить модель связывающей таблицы, сохранив при этом текущие навигационные свойства `Tags { get; set; }` и `Products { get; set; }`.

Добавляю модель и ее конфигурацию:

```
public class ProductTags
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}

public class ProductTagsConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProductTags>
{
    public ProductTagsConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(p => new { p.ProductId, p.TagId });
        ToTable("ProductTags");
    }
}
```

После добавления начинает ругаться из за одинаковых конфигураций:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> TagProduct: Name: The EntitySet 'TagProduct' with schema 'dbo' and
>   table 'ProductTags' was already defined. Each EntitySet must refer to
>   a unique schema and table.

Если удалить `TagConfiguration`, нельзя будет обращаться к навигационным свойствам. Замена текущих свойств на `public ICollection<ProductTags> ProductTags { get; set; }` не подходит.

Возможно ли сделать конфигурацию так, чтобы можно было работать и с промежуточной моделью `ProductTags`, и через текущие навигационные свойства?

---

Для чего нужно такое решение:

Код пишется для десктопного приложения к существующей базе. Требуется выполнять фильтрацию по тегам для выбранных продуктов. Если делать без связывающей модели, придется использовать `ctx.Products.Where(...).Include(p => p.Tags).ToList()` при получении продуктов. А т.к. продуктов может быть несколько тысяч, это будет выполняться медленно. Если же ввести модель связывающей таблицы, можно будет получить список связей один раз, а затем выполнять фильтрацию уже в памяти.

Получаем все теги и связи при загрузке программы:

```
public readonly Dictionary<int, List<Tag>> ProductsAndTags = new Dictionary<int, List<Tag>>();

public void LoadProductsAndTags()
{
    using (var context = new DbContext())
    {
        var productsAndTags = context.ProductTags.AsNoTracking()
            .Include(x => x.Tag)
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in productsAndTags)
        {
            if (!ProductsAndTags.ContainsKey(item.ProductId))
                ProductsAndTags.Add(item.ProductId, new List<Tag>());
            ProductsAndTags[item.ProductId].Add(item.Tag);
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь можно получать все теги для каждого продукта очень быстро:

```
if (Db.Tags.ProductsAndTags.ContainsKey(product.Id))
    product.Tags = Db.Tags.ProductsAndTags[product.Id];
```

Почему нужно оставить существующие навигационные свойства?
Сейчас они используются в разных частях программы. Если от них отказаться, придется вносить много изменений.

Программа дальше развиваться не будет, за исключением багфиксов, однако требуется решить вопрос фильтрации по тегам. И чтобы не тратить на это много времени, было решено сделать такое решение в лоб. Понимаю, что выглядит не правильно, но лучшего варианта, к сожалению, мне пока не видится.

Comment: Я не понимаю что вы делаете, у вас связь многие-ко-многим между `Product` и `Tag`, EF добавит промежуточную таблицу самостоятельно, зачем вы пытаетесь добавить ее вручную? Естественно будет конфликт. Зачем вам нужно явно работать с этой промежуточной таблицей? Скорее всего есть решение без явного ее использования, опишите свою задачу подробнее.

Comment: Напишите, для каких операций вам понадобилась модель ProductTags -- мы покажем, что это можно сделать БЕЗ создания модели, оперируя только теми, что созданы автоматически. Сейчас же задача выглядит как [XY-проблема](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/213987).

Comment: @Андрей, АК  дополнил вопрос.

Comment: @Skrim, так, а если вообще выбросить из `Product` свойство `public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }` и из `Tag` свойство `public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }` и пользоваться Linq в ОЗУ уже? Либо пометить эти свойства атрибутом чтобы их игнорировал EF и заполнять их вручную при необходимости.

Comment: @Андрей да, думал об этом. Но тогда придется переписывать текущий функционал добавления тегов, добавления продуктов с тегами. Сейчас это сделано через эти свойства. Вот и решил спросить возможно ли пользоваться и ими и соединяющей моделью одновременно, как-то сконфигурировать все без конфликтов.